# java getDeclaredAnnotations is not returning one attribute from an annotation

Tags: java, annotations

java getDeclaredAnnotations is not returning one attribute from an annotation.

Steps:

1) Annotations are present in external Java class ( Carrier.java) which is compiled  and loaded dynamically :

```
@Facets(xpath = "/Carrier/Carrier_Id", displayString = "Carrier")
private String carrier_Id;
```

2) The annotation @Facets has this definition :

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.PARAMETER,
    ElementType.TYPE })

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Facets {

@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER,
        ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public static @interface FacetDefinition {
    String xsdAttributeName() default VOID_STRING;
}

@FacetDefinition
String xpath() default VOID_STRING;

@FacetDefinition
String entityName() default VOID_STRING;
```

3) Below code to retrieve annotation attributes from the dynamically loaded class - (Carrier.class) :

```
Annotation[] annotations = field2.getDeclaredAnnotations();
for(Annotation annotation : annotations){

 if(annotation instanceof Facets)
 {
  Facets myAnnotation = (Facets) annotation;
  xpath = myAnnotation.xpath();
  displayName = myAnnotation.displayString();
  }
```

4) Value of one attribute - xpath is returned correctly, but second attribute -  displayString is always returned as an empty string.

displayString value is present in Carrier.class file:

```
javap -v Carrier.class
 #38 = Utf8               xpath
 #39 = Utf8               /Carrier/Carrier_Id
 #40 = Utf8               displayString
 #41 = Utf8               Carrier
```

But getDeclaredAnnotations is not retrieving this value, instead returning an empty string.

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Could you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What I can see for now is that your `@Facets(xpath = "/Carrier/Carrier_Id", displayString = "Carrier")`. `displayString` initialized to `Carrier` value

Comment: @J-Alex , This is how Facets annotation appears in an external Java file, which is dynamically compiled and loaded.
The annotations from this class are then fetched dynamically using getDeclaredAnnotations, but only one attribute -  xpath is retrieved, while displayString is returned as an empty string.

Not sure if I can reduce it to a minimal example.